# Displaying Compass At specific location on Device 

Tags: android

I want to display the compass(Image View) on device at a specific location.I tried Like this below code to display the compass view on device but the thing is i need to display at Specific location and small view only but it occupies entire screen space.Can you help me to fix an compass image at specific location.Using this line of code i am getting an image form Drawable folder.  this.setImageResource(R.drawable.compassrose); So how to fix that image at specific location.

```
Class1:-
         public class Compass extends Activity implements SensorListener {
  SensorManager sensorManager;
  static final int sensor = SensorManager.SENSOR_ORIENTATION;
  Rose rose;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449390501/Android_System_Services.html
    // Set full screen view
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
//FLAG_FULLSCREEN    
//FLAG_SCALED
    rose = new Rose(this);

    setContentView(rose);

    // get sensor manager
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
  }

  // register to listen to sensors
  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor);
  }

  // unregister
  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
  }

  // Ignore for now
  public void onAccuracyChanged(int sensor, int accuracy) {
  }

  // Listen to sensor and provide output
  public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
    if (sensor != Compass.sensor)
      return;
    int orientation = (int) values[0];
    rose.setDirection(orientation);
  }
}


Class 2:-
             public class Rose extends ImageView {
  Paint paint;
  int direction = 0;

  public Rose(Context context) {
    super(context);

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

    this.setImageResource(R.drawable.compassrose);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int height = this.getHeight();
    int width = this.getWidth();

    canvas.rotate(direction, width / 2, height / 2);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
  }

  public void setDirection(int direction) {
    this.direction = direction;
    this.invalidate();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to position an ImageView in an Android layout? Have you tried with XML, or does it need to be set programmatically?

If you are just trying to position an ImageView, then try going through some of the layout tutorials: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html

If not, then please add more detail to your question

Answer (score 2):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    rose = new Rose(this);
    txtorientation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    compassLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.CompassLayout);
    compassLayout.addView(rose); 
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
    Log.d("Compass", "onCreated");
}
```